# Visual Studio 2010 Web Deploy Config Transformation Based on Publish Profile Name

Tags: web-config-transform, webdeploy

I've a Project called TestWebSite.

I create 2 Solution Configuration (Debug, Release)

Then I create a Config Transformation for Web.Config.

Then I create 2 "Publishing Profile"

1) Test.testwebsite.com
2) Online.TestWebSite.com

I need to generate 2 different Config Transformation based on the name of the "Publishing Profile".

If I publish on the (1)"Test" website I need to use a specific Connection Sterings.

It is possible to crate a Config Transformation that interact with the "Publishing Profile Name" or something that permit to generate changes based on the "Publishing Profile Name".

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With VS2012 or with the VS2010 extension mentioned at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/06/15/visual-studio-2010-web-publish-updates.aspx, you can create per-profile transforms.  There isn't yet tooling to generate the transform files in the IDE, but you can copy one of the existing transform files (e.g. Web.Release.config) and include it in your project.